# Changing image size in JSON file

Tags: leaflet, json

I am wondering how to change image size, available under the link in JSON file.

I base on the example:

http://www.gistechsolutions.com/leaflet/DEMO/baseball/BaseballPanel.html

which uses  a links to the icon, based on the web.
This is obviously fine, although the linked image must have a certain size like:

```
"Logo": "http:\/\/mlb.mlb.com\/mlb\/images\/team_logos\/logo_atl_79x76.jpg",
        "LeagueLogo": "http:\/\/mlb.mlb.com\/mlb\/images\/nl_75x75.png",
```

I have changed the link and put another one, so my JSON file (properties) currently looks like this:

```
"properties": {
    "name": "PE1 5RX",
    "MS_Ref": "REG/LYVELLYGDNS",
    "Owner": "Long Term Reversions (Dulwich) Limited",
    "Client_Ref": "LYVELLYGDNS",
    "Address": "The Keep, Lyvelly Gardens, Peterborough",
    "Postcode": "PE1 5RX",
    "Units": 18,
    "Logo": "https:\/\/www.cityfibre.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/09\/CF- 
logo-New-Green.png",
    "No_Under__H_Lease": 0,
    "FH_Title": "CB331893",
    "FH_Title_2": 0,
    "Possible_Query__over__availablity": "No"
  }
```

and attached logo is enormously big.

I tried to make sth like this:

```
"Logo": "<a href='https:\/\/www.cityfibre.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/09\/CF-logo-New-Green.png' width='100'></a>"
```

But it doesn't work at all.

To make the graph running i need a rough URL in the quote.

How to change the size of this image to make it more adjusted to the particular map/website? Unless it's necessary to upload the smaller image on the server first and next link it to the JSON?

The logo, which I am interested in is under the link below:

https://www.cityfibre.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/CF-logo-New-Green.png[image]

Comment: <img src=" + feature.properties.Logo +" style='width:120px;height:120px;'>    Your logo is an image not a hyperlink, a hyperlinked image would open an html page. example...<a href="../html-link.htm">
<img src=" + feature.properties.Logo +" width="120" height="120"></a>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, add width and height attribute to img element like shown below.

```
//place attributes in panel table.
    var fieldA=document.getElementById('pict');
    fieldA.innerHTML='<img src="' +e.target.feature.properties.Logo +'">';
```

with

```
//place attributes in panel table.
    var fieldA=document.getElementById('pict');
    fieldA.innerHTML='<img src="' +e.target.feature.properties.Logo +'" width = 50 height = 50>';
```

Your solution of changing to

```
"Logo": "<a href='https:\/\/www.cityfibre.com\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/09\/CF-logo-New-Green.png' width='100'></a>"
```

will not work as in the code it is inside `src` attribute.